# Generate totally unique token that has never been used using php

Tags: php, security, token, unique

So I want a way to generate an authentication token to pass back to client so it can then use this to pass with each request.

However what is the best practice for generating unique tokens that have never been used before.

I need to guarantee uniqueness so I cannot totally base it on the php uniqid() as there is a minimal possibility that two users logon at exactly the same time (really small chance but cannot take that chance).

Is it bad practice to prefix a uniqid() value with their username?

Also is the time stamp that uniqid() is based on susceptible to duplicate values when clocks go back/forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot boils down to how long the code can become, how hard you need it to be unique, how hard it needs to be to unpredictable, and if you have a list of valid codes.

**length**

First-off: simple math implies that if you have to be able to generate an infinite number of unique random strings that are unique, that you CANNOT limit the length of said string (It'll become infinite ...).

If you have to store the used values in a database, one typically needs a maximum length.

Regardless, unlimited length strings create a lot of hazards.

**how unique ?**

Obviously just using time is not very unique, but you can add things to make collisions less and less likely, all the while making it harder to predict.

If you have a list of (currently) valid codes, you can always validate the generated code against the existing database and regenerate a new one should a collision with a currently valid one occur.

Obviously a simple ever increasing counter will guarantee uniqueness, but it's not handy as it's not length limited, extremely predictable etc.

**hard to predict**

Typically authentication codes that could be guessed are a terrible security idea. So you need to defend against that.

**Combining it all**

To combine it all, you can create a concatenation of a string from:

- A fixed, but secret string (make it long) consider it a passphrase that makes guessing your input extremely hard
- IP address of the client
- port number used by the client
- time & date
- a pseudo random number
- the string the client uses to identify itself
- username
- ...

You don't need to take all, the order etc. is all up to you. The more the merrier.

Once you have that string, you pick a hash function, the longer the output of the hash, the less likely collisions will be, but the more storage the code will use in your database.

A good choice nowadays would be sha-1 or sha-256  (md5 is a bit too broken to be used in anything new).

This gives you a code that is fixed in length, changes dramatically even if you just change one bit in the input, is next to impossible to predict for an attacker, and has a tiny chance of causing a collision.

How tiny ? It's extremely unlikely, see the math here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24732/probability-of-sha256-collisions-for-certain-amount-of-hashed-values

If you need to exclude the possibility completely and not allow an unlimited length of codes, you can only check it against the codes in use and should it be found, you can generate a new one.

**TL;DR**

You can add other things aside of time, e.g. IP address of remote side of the connection, pseudo random number, process id, a fixed string you keep secret, etc. mix that in and make a hash using e.g. sha-256 and you have a fixed length hard to predict code.

The risk of collisions exists, but it's tremendously small if you give it enough input, to eliminate it: check against the list of in use codes.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you :)

Comment: Been thinking about this a little bit more and one final question. I want the token to be guaranteed unique for that user, is it bad practice to prefix the user id (not the username but the unique auto increment int) to the end of the token, this will guarantee the token could never be reused by a different user. Just a bit cautious that if a token is refreshed but isn't passed to the client app correctly and that client then attempts to connect again but (super slim chance of it happening), another client user has refreshed their token and because the token doesn't exist in the db anymore....

Comment: .....,this new client is given this same token value on the off chance, but then the client app that didn't get the refreshed token tried to connect again and because that client now has the same token as this other user will now have access to this other users account, slim chance but I need to take every effort to prevent any potential unauthorised access. Hope this is clear

Comment: What you seem to be proposing is to have the client claim a code and a userid , can't hurt to do that as long as you check that the claimed user id matches on your system.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly, just didn't know if there was a potential leak of info if I am sending the id (not the username) to and from the api (over https),

Comment: Ok so what I am proposing is:

using php/openssl function - openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(24), convertering that to bin2hex(),Then appending to the end a php uniqid($userIDNumberPrefix, with more entropy) 

Then base64 encoding this string - or is there no need to base64 encode this? I was thinking if someone was trying to brute force then at least using base64 introduces upper and lower case (case sensitive colum in the db) so making more combinations to test?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have a database where you store those tokens so that you can check if it is a correct one or not. If that is true you can just generate the token the way you prefer(i.e. uniqid(), random string,...whatever you like) and check if that already exists in the db. It if doesn't exists you are good to go with it otherwise you can generate a new one and do the check again.

Comment: Did think of that but would cause a little more strain on the database doing a check on over potentially 1 millions users each time a new token is generated. But this is my fall back solution if I cannot work out a way to base a token on time stamp as well as a unique value e.g. Username.

Comment: Appending or prepending the username to the timestamp should work, maybe you can even hash it so that it won't be easily readable.

Comment: I guess if I hash it though it may be more susceptible to collisions, it's more unique to use the value of the time stamp and username but I don't particularly want to send the username

Comment: I wrote it badly, what I meant was to hash the username only and append the timestamp to the hashed username. PHP would be like $token=sha1($username).microtime();

Comment: Ah I see, what I was thinking about using was the password_hash with bcrypt in php jut for the username and do what you say and prefix this to the uniqid() function to guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: Given that two usernames can't be equal then tokens would be unique

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UUID, Universally Unique IDentifier. The specs are [rfc4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

**An excerpt:**

> One of the main reasons for using UUIDs is that no centralized
>      authority is required to administer them (although one format uses
>      IEEE 802 node identifiers, others do not).  As a result, generation
>      on demand can be completely automated, and used for a variety of
>      purposes.  The UUID generation algorithm described here supports very
>      high allocation rates of up to 10 million per second per machine if
>      necessary, so that they could even be used as transaction IDs.

**UUID Generators**

There are UUID generators for various languages, just make sure the implementation uses the algorithms in the RFC-4122 spec. A lot of them will simply use a random number for each hex octet of the UUID, which will cause collisions.

Comment: Thanks, any example libraries for php?

Comment: You can use the uniqid function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php. It generates a unique string based on the current time in microseconds

Answer (score -2):

This method works for me...

```
$token = md5(date['u']);
```

Uses number of seconds since the epoch (Jan 1 1970) so almost a guarantee you get a unique one time value. MD5 turns that into a 32 character string. The chance of 2 identical values is still not quite zero but extremely close to zero .

Using date w/ 'u' parameter won't be an issue due to DST.

Comment: First of all, that is NOT guaranteed to provide a unique id, since it is not only possibly, but actually quite likely that two or more (perhaps many more!) users will log in within the space of a single second, which will generate the same token. Secondly, it may be theoretically possible (though unlikely) that two *different* dates will happen to generate the same MD5 sum.